# Can delayed job's reschedule_at be configured globally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, delayed-job

In delayed job, can I configure reschedule_at globally, rather than having to do so on each job?

I'm using Rails 4.x and ActiveRecord.

Comment: I am not delayed_job pro, do you use custom jobs or what?

Comment: @Aleksey if I could avoid custom jobs, I would. As it is, I had to create custom jobs in order to add a `reschedule_at` for this purpose.

Comment: I see. You can create some mixin with `reschedule_at` method and include it to your custom jobs, can't you? Of course it is not brilliant solution but in source code of delayed_job I can see that `reschedule_at` is called on a job itself so I think there is no way to configure it globally.